# Error in first Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I've been trying to create my first Shiny app in R which would display data points from a time interval in a day the longest possible being between 15 and 20.25 hours. dat is the original datatable which had all 24 hours and it is already initialized. I'm making dat5 to be a new datatable with the 2 inputs from the slider as the new time interval. My code is below and I'm getting this error in the actual app: "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" although the slider appears to be good. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the error I'm getting in the console with the code under it:

**Error**

```
Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { 
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Stack trace (innermost first):
    68: output$plot1
     1: runApp

Warning messages:
1: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: title
2: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: keyword
3: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: alias
4: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: title
5: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: keyword
6: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: alias
```

**Code**

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(sliderInput(Tc, "Time Interval", min = 15, max =20.25,
                         2,    value = c(15,20.25))),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dat5 <- reactive({
    dat5 <- copy(dat[Tc %between%c(input[1],input[2])])
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(dat2, aes(x = dat5$Tc, y = dat5$LastPrice)) +
      geom_line(size = 2, alpha = 0.5) + 
      geom_point(size = 3) + 
      xlab("Time") +
      ylab("Price")+
      theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.position = 'bottom')
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: After I did that it says Error: Single-bracket indexing of reactivevalues object is not allowed

Comment: I'm not sure why dat5 should be referred to as dat5(). It is a data.table not a function or am I missing something?

Comment: Now is is saying "ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class reactive" which means I just need to fix something within the reactive function but I'm unsure what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I constructed a simple working example:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

set.seed(707)

dat <- data.table(
  Tc = seq(0, 23.75, by = 0.25),
  LastPrice = exp(rnorm(24 * 4))
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(sliderInput('Tc', "Time Interval", min = 15, max =20.25,
                             2, value = c(15,20.25))),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat5 <- reactive({
    dat5 <- copy(dat[Tc %between% c(input$Tc[1],input$Tc[2])])
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dat5(),
           aes(x = Tc,
               y = LastPrice)) +
      geom_line(size = 2,
                alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 3) +
      xlab("Time") +
      ylab("Price")+
      theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
            legend.position = 'bottom')
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Necessary corrections:

- The first argument to `sliderInput` needs to be a character value.
- This value is the ID for that input, and needs to be used to get the slider's values. So `c(input[1], input[2])` needs to be changed to `c(input$Tc[1], input$TC[2])`

Another change:

- Because of the usual `ggplot2` syntax, you don't need to specify `dat5()$` before the column names in the aesthetics arguments.